# Is it possible to send an email asking for a job after refusing it?

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, software-industry

I've been offered a senior PHP developer position last week, I didn't apply, they reached out for me I did the interview, while leaving, I told the boss that if there are better candidates please take them, I like the job but don't need it since I have two jobs now.

I didn't want to take the position from someone in need, plus the fact that I just started working for my current company, didn't want to be the guy who leaves for a better offer immediately. I like my current team.

However few days after the interview, my senior started requesting that I stop working remotely which is something that is costing me too much, we had a verbal agreement that I work remotely, they didn't respect it, what can I do? I'm paying 1/3 of my paycheck just to get to work now.

And my other employer got evolved in the local election and forgot about the company.

I am left, with a job that is costing too much money and another uncertain job with an uncertain boss.

Is it possible to  resend email to the other company, telling them to reconsider me if I was a good candidate or not?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context for this prospective new role? What prevents a previous candidate from just sending an email to the manager?

Comment: @Kozaky Okay just did, after reading your comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Is it possible to send an email asking for a job after refusing it?"

You can sit down in front of a computer and write an emial and click the send button, so it is clearly possible.

May may think "what a stupid answer, I know that, I mean is it appropriate". For that:

- I do not care. This is not what you ask. You ask literally whether it is possible.
- You should not care. There is no damage in sending this email, so at the end whatever norms may or may not exist - what is your downside?

The second point here is quite important. Many people follow protocols. Many successfull people know when to not follow them. In your case there literally is nothing that can happen to you if you send the mail (except some person you likely never talk to ever again thinking you are a little harhs or whatever), with the alternative that yes, the job may still be available. No downside. So, literally it boils down to acutally being able to send a mail, which is my answer - yes, you can.

Comment: Yep, chances are if the job is still available and you were good enough for them then, you are good enough now.

Answer (score 1):

This is an unusual thing to be doing but not unheard of. And there is nothing wrong with doing it.

What I would recommend however is not emailing, but phoning. There is a reasonable chance that the company started the process of offering the job to someone else. If you get in quickly you may be able to accept the offer before they do. Phoning is the fastest way to make this happen. (If you can't speak to an actual person on the phone you might send mots of messages by different means).

When you do, explain to them that there has been an unexpected change in your current job. They will understand, and probably be pleased.